# What's a good way to store class properties and load at run time?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have a messaging producer (RabbitMQ) and depending on what kind of message i have to send, i need to change the routing key and exchange at runtime.

Given this i'd implemented a strategy to load each class with specific properties, but it's not appear a good solution.

For example:

```
    public class MyProducerStrategy1 extends RabbitMessagingProducer {

    private static final String ROUTING_KEY = "order1";
    private static final String EXCHANGE = "myexchange1";

    @Override
    String getRoutingKey() {
        return ROUTING_KEY;
    }

    @Override
    String getExchange() {
        return EXCHANGE;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Message message) {
        super.sendMessage(message);
    }
}


public class MyProducerStrategy2 extends RabbitMessagingProducer {

    private static final String ROUTING_KEY = "fullfilment";
    private static final String EXCHANGE = "myexchange2";

    @Override
    String getRoutingKey() {
        return ROUTING_KEY;
    }

    @Override
    String getExchange() {
        return EXCHANGE;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Message message) {
        super.sendMessage(message);
    }
}

public abstract class RabbitMessagingProducer implements MessagingProducerStrategy {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    abstract String getRoutingKey();

    abstract String getExchange();

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Message message) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(getExchange(), getRoutingKey(), message);
    }
}
```

Does it make sense? or there's another approach to load there properties and have maybe one class?

Comment: I would use a properties file instead and have a single class control what variables are pulled. Don't think hard coding values is a good idea.

Comment: understand.. this single class will load the properties and then construct the producer?

Comment: That depends on your requirements, but generally speaking i would construct my message in one class and publish the message in another. Efficient error handling is key, not to mention re-usability.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create multiple class for this scenario.

1. load the files from a property file based on the message.
2. Another option is to create a static map of values with message types as the key and routing key as the value. Fetch the values from the map based on the message type.